# using faye over https with self generated certificate

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ssl-certificate, faye

I am using faye for publishing and subscribing messages. Now i have to move my application over ssl. I am running my application `https://localhost:44477` and my faye server runs as `https://<ip>:9292`. And i have to use self signed certificate for my application. I generated one self signed certificate and for using this, I add exception for my rails application when pop-up for `untrusted connection` comes on browser.

Problem occurs on accessing faye. Since i am calling faye from layouts as `https://<ip>:9292/faye.js`, browser needs to add exception for this url separately. But, since this I am accessing from layout, no separate pop-up comes for this, and it fails silently, till i open this in another browser and add exception.

Is there any way to handle adding exceptions for requests from backend/layouts?